# Handle UIGestureRecognizer in multiple views

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UIView to which I added a `UITapGestureRecognizer`. I added a `UICollectionView` as a subview. The problem is that `UICollectionView` uses `UITapGestureRecognizers` to catch taps on the collection view cells, and the parent UIView catches them. Is there a way to pass these recognizers so that they are handled by both the `UIView` and the `UICollectionView`?

** Edit - adding a code example **

```
let mainView = UIView()
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(foo))
mainView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

let collectionView = UICollectionView(/*...*/)
collectionView.delegate = self
mainView.addSubview(collectionView)

func foo(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    // Will be called when I tap on mainView
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Will NOT be called when I tap on collectionView's cells
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Provide a code example.

Comment: you. mean you want your gesture to be handled from both UIView and UICollectionView?

Comment: @BrandonStillitano provided :)

Comment: @MukeshShakya Yes

Comment: You want your foo function to call only if the touch is from mainView right?

Comment: Enable user interaction of *UICollectionView* and check

Comment: @MukeshShakya No. If the touch is from the main view, outside the collection, then foo() should be called. If the touch is on a collectionView's cell, then both foo() and the didSelectItemAt functions should be called

Comment: If you want your gesture function to be called while the tap in cell to then simply call the function while the cell is selected.

Comment: @MukeshShakya I simplified the views structure for publishing this question, in my project the structure is more complex and the collection view is deeper inside the hierarchy. So letting the collectionView know about foo() doesn't fit. But the answer you suggested below helped me. Thanks!

Comment: You can simply call a function which can interact with the view to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this from `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`. Assign delegate to your gesture and use the extension below. The `Delegate` below allows gesture to receive touch only when touched outside from the `collectionView`.

```
extension SharePathViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        let point = touch.location(in: view)
        return !collectionView.frame.contains(point)
    }
}
```

If you want your gesture function to be called while the tap in cell to then simply call the function while the cell is selected.